# Can CSS values changed relatively?

Tags: html, css

```
#foo{font-size:14px;}
```

*Now #foo has 14px font size*

```
#foo{font-size:$-2px} // Hypothetical code
```

*Now #foo has 12px font size. (14px - 2px)*

Is this possible by any means? To dynamically change the value of a selector.

Comment: You can use em - relative to the parent.
For example, if font-size:1.5em it means that it will be 1.5 times larger than the font size of the parent. 
Also if you need real calculations, I recommend using less or sass.

Comment: Css currently don't have any method to modify value relative to current value. We can use javascript for that.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you post any links with examples, or where can I start?

Comment: But we have some relative units like em, ex, rem etc. which may be of some use.

Comment: `font-size: smaller`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rem` which will refer to the global font-size.

```css
:root
{
  font-size : 14px;
}

#foo
{
  font-size : calc(1rem - 2px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  I am a 14px text according to the root font-size
</div>
<div id="foo">
  I am a 12 pixel text according to the rem font-size
</div>
```

**EXPLANATION**

The rem will refer to the global css. So when processing (1rem - 2px), this is actually (14px - 2px).

Comment: Hmm, even though you are correct, this is a custom answer to my general problem. This snippet you wrote, will only work for this exact same thing. Unfortunately it's doesn't provide a straight solution because maybe there isn't one. Perhaps with SASS/LESS. Still, thanks for your time!

Comment: Indead, when dealing with complexes calculus, SASS reveals to be powerfull. This is the limit of this technic.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Using calc() method**

I don't understand what do you mean by dynamically changed. But to do relative calculation, use `calc()` method.

Example:

```
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

**2. Using preprocessor like SASS**

You might also want to check `Sass` for preprocessing. One of the well supported features are, variables.

You can define variables and do some calculations.

```
$body-size: 200px;

body {
  width: $body-size/2 ;
}
```

Here is a simple example I created: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rh2qds1q/2/)

Reference: [SASS](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-variables)

**3. Using jQuery**

The OP mentioned about changing the sizes whenever the window size changed. One approach would be using jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    $('#item').width(width);
});
```

**4. Using `vw` and `vh` attributes**

The OP mentioned about wanting to change the sizes according to the viewport in the comment.

`vw` and `vh` is relative to the viewport width and height respectively.

```
div.responsive {
   width: 10vw; /* 10% of viewport width */
   height: 10vh; /* 10% of viewport height */
   background-color: black; /* Just to make it visible while testing */
}
```

Comment: This doens't quite help me since calc is used for an already known value. I want to use a code where I won't be able to know the 1st value (in my example, the 14px value).

Comment: Maybe the word "dynamically" wasn't the right one. I am trying to explain that if it's possible with CSS or any other means, to change the value of a selector without knowing the value it already has.

I don't know #foo has 14px font size. But i want it to have -2px of what it already has as a value.

Comment: @dominotrix: How come you don't know the size of #foo? Is it set somewhere? Maybe you can use variables in Sass. Then reset the size to $variable -2px. Updated

Comment: That would be helpful when building the responsiveness of a website. For every 100px that the viewport is decreasing, I want the #foo selector to have 100px substracted from it's current.

That wouldn't need me to write media queries: [at]1200px {width:600px} - [at]1100px {width:500px} ... and so on.

And I have no idea how to install SASS or LESS.

Comment: @dominotrix: I believe you can do that with calc. calc(100%-100px)

Comment: @dominotrix: I updated with some approached that might works.

Answer (score 1):

My $ 2/100.

1. CSS as of now, doesn't allow **cross-browser** variables in truest of sense, but you may be interested in this [CSS Variables Official Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility).
2. CSS not supporting variables, is one of the most important reason CSS Preprocessors exist. eg. [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).
3. You can use `font-size` and then relative `em` to control some of the elements properties, but its somewhat whaky, and you will end up having to individually specify font-sizes on children elements.

   ```
   .example {
       font-size: 20px;
       border-radius: .5em; // 10px (20*.5)
       padding: 2em; // 40px (20*2)
   }
   ```